# Prevent WebBrowser control from stealing focus?

Tags: .net, javascript, browser, focus

Is there a way to stop the WebBrowser control from causing its parent form to bring itself to the front?

If you use the InvokeScript method to invoke a JavaScript function that calls focus() on an iframe within the main parent document, it will cause the window to bring itself directly to the front(or atleast cause the taskbar icon to start flashing). Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

### **Update:**

I've found a temporary answer to my problem.

When the WebBrowser's parent Form's Deactive event is fired, I remove the WebBrowser from its container, and re-add it when its old parent form is activated again.

It's kind of hacky, but it works. I'm open to any better suggestions, though.

Comment: It is probably enough to make it invisible instead of full removal. It is certainly a way out here. Sorry if I didn't understand before that it was about a form in .net, instead of a javascript/html problem

Comment: @Abel: It's mostly a javascript/browser problem causing a WinForms problem. I did try just making the browser control invisible first, but it didn't solve it until I flat out removed the control from the form.

Comment: I completely rewrote the answer. It is not an easy task you're up to, but take my answer, tweak it to your needs, and you can be all set

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***EDIT:*** complete question rewritten, I misunderstood original question

Let's generalize the problem: a control or component that you don't have control about, can call `FlashWindow` (the Win32 API function) to get attention from the user. You don't want that.

There are generally two solutions for this: use API hooking or Message hooking. Since API hooking is complex and involved, I'll present a solution for Message hooking.

### FlashWindow

Microsoft doesn't explain in so many words what `FlashWindow` does. Unfortunately, it doesn't send a specific message (say `WM_FLASH` or similar), which would've made it easier to capture and annul this behavior. Instead, `FlashWindow` does three things:

1. It sets a system timer for the flashing intervals
2. It sends a `WM_NCACTIVATE` message for the first flash
3. It sends a `WM_NCACTIVATE` message when the timer expires (on receiving `WM_SYSTIMER`)

Depending on how the component calls FlashWindow, this can be indefinite, until another timeout occurs, until it has focus or just once. Each WM_NCACTIVATE message activates or deactivates the NC-zone (caption bar, button on taskbar). It doesn't change the input the focus.

### Challenge

Any solution for preventing the flashing is a bit involved. The main challenges are:

1. the `WM_SYSTIMER` event is sent asynchronously with PostMessage and is not received by the `WndProc` method of the Form (it only processes synchronous messages)
2. the `WM_NCACTIVATE` messages are also used when the user clicks on the title bar or taskbar button to set input focus, simply canceling these messages will have unwanted side effects
3. FlashWindow will always flash at least once, regardless of the `WM_SYSTIMER` firing or not.

The `WM_SYSTIMER` message is undocumented. It has the value `0x0118` and is used internally by Windows to time such things as the blinking of the caret, the delay in a menu opening etc. Here it is used for the time between the flashes.

### Solution

The solution I present here is a basis for further development. It is not a complete solution, but it solves the issue in many cases. Place the following in your form code:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    bool messageHandled = false;
    if (m.Msg == WM_NCACTIVATE)
    {
        // add logic here to determine user action, losing focus etc and set 
        // messageHandled and m.Result only when user action is not the cause 
        // of triggering WM_NCACTIVATE
        m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
        messageHandled = true;
    }

    if(!messageHandled)
        base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

The above code already prevents flashing completely. You'll have to add some logic to change the title bar, because totally ignoring `WM_NCACTIVATE` means that the title bar will look active all the time, even when it isn't.

The following code gives you more control. You can use it to react to the flashing itself. Normally, a main window does not receive `WM_SYSTIMER` events so often, but you'll have to experiment whether you should make exceptions. It seems that for `FlashWindow`, the `wParam` is always set to `0xFFF8`, but do experiment with it, as this is not documented anywhere.

```
public class MyMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    // an application can have many windows, only filter for one window at the time
    IntPtr FilteredHwnd = IntPtr.Zero;

    public MyMessageFilter(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        this.FilteredHwnd = hwnd;
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (this.FilteredHwnd == m.HWnd && m.Msg == WM_SYSTIMER)
            return true;     // stop handling the message further
        else
            return false;    // all other msgs: handle them
    }
}
```

To activate this messagefilter, simply add the following line somewhere in your form load event:

```
Application.AddMessageFilter(new MyMessageFilter(this.Handle));
```

The following constants should be placed at class level. They are used in both code sections above:

```
public const UInt32 WM_SYSTIMER = 0x0118;
public const UInt32 WM_NCACTIVATE = 0x86;
```

### Conclusion

Though the problem itself is solvable, it is by far not easy. With the above handles, you should get quite far. Use the filter to prevent the flashing, but then the first "flash" still happens. Use the `WinProc` override to prevent the first one too, but add some logic to prevent your application from behaving too oddly (i.e.: always inactive title bar, or always active). You already have some code that you can combine with this to set some boolean flags.

Comment: I like this answer, though it seems a bit convoluted for what I need. That is, I have a specific setup for my own app so my hacky method isn't going to be a problem for this instance. However, I'm going to integrate this into another app. Thank you!

Comment: I totally agree, it is a complex workaround, simply because there's no such thing as `if is_flashing then`. I wished there was another way, but afaict, there isn't, really.

Answer (score 5):

Implement IProtectFocus::AllowFocusChange in an object

Implement IServiceProvider on the same object that implements IOleClientSite, then 
respond to a IServiceProvider::QueryService for SID_SProtectFocus with an object that exposes IProtectFocus

This is a new interface in IE7, so old versions are out of luck.

Comment: Do you, by any chance, have a working sample how you can do this in C#?

Comment: http://www.google.com/codesearch#search&q=IProtectfocus+package:http://csexwb2%5C.googlecode%5C.com

Comment: thanks for your response! what I meant was actually a sample code on how to use the interface. the code snippet of the c# implementation helps but what's next?

Comment: Once you implemented the interfaces IE will call your implementation. There is no need to call the interfaces by yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still cannot follow. Do I need to inherit from the web browser control and implement the interface? I did that, set pfAllow to false and it doesn't seem to work. Web sites like google search still steals the focus... I'm not sure if I'm doing it right...

Comment: It depends on how your webbrowser class implements IOleClientSite. For example, if you use Windows Forms, IOleClientSite is implemented by WebBrowser.WebBrowserSite and you need to derive from it to implement IServiceProvider, then derive from WebBrowser to use your new site. If you use the ActiveX with your own IOleClientSite implementation like csexwb sample then add IServiceProvider to your own IOleClientSite implementation to return a IProtectFocus implementation when service is queried.