# WebBrowser control keyboard and focus behavior

Tags: wpf, keyboard, wpf-controls, focus, webbrowser-control

Apparently, there are some serious keyboard and focus issues with [WPF WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx). I've put together a trivial WPF app, just a WebBrowser and two buttons. The app loads a very basic editable HTML markup (`<body contentEditable='true'>some text</body>`) and demonstrates the following:

- Tabbing is misbehaving. User needs to hit Tab twice to see the caret (text cursor) inside WebBrowser and be able to type.
- When user switches away from the app (e.g., with Alt-Tab), then goes back, the caret is gone and she is unable to type at all. A physical mouse click into the WebBrowser's window client area is required to get back the caret and keystrokes.
- Inconsistently, a dotted focus rectangle shows up around WebBrowser (when tabbing, but not when clicking). I could not find a way to get rid of it (`FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"` does not help).
- Internally, WebBrowser never receives the focus. That's true for both logical focus ([FocusManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.aspx)) and input focus ([Keyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.aspx)). The `Keyboard.GotKeyboardFocusEvent` and `FocusManager.GotFocusEvent` events never get fired for WebBrowser (although they both do for buttons *in the same focus scope*). Even when the caret is inside WebBrowser, `FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(mainWindow)` points to a previously focused element (a button) and `Keyboard.FocusedElement` is `null`. At the same time, `((IKeyboardInputSink)this.webBrowser).HasFocusWithin()` returns `true`.

I'd say, such behaviour is almost too dysfunctional to be true, but that's how it works. I could probably come up with some hacks to fix it and bring it in row with native WPF controls like `TextBox`. Still I hope, maybe I'm missing something obscure yet simple here. Has anyone dealt with a similar problem? Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

At this point, I'm inclined to develop an in-house WPF wrapper for WebBrowser ActiveX Control, based upon [HwndHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndhost.aspx). We are also **[considering other alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119125/options-for-embedding-chromium-instead-of-ie-webbrowser-control-with-wpf-c)** to WebBrowser, such as Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF).

The VS2012 project can be downloaded from [here](https://sites.google.com/site/uk3000/WpfWebBrowserTest.zip?attredirects=0&d=1) in case someone wants to play with it.

This is XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfWebBrowserTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="640" Height="480" Background="LightGray">

    <StackPanel Margin="20,20,20,20">
        <ToggleButton Name="btnLoad" Focusable="True" IsTabStop="True" Content="Load" Click="btnLoad_Click" Width="100"/>

        <WebBrowser Name="webBrowser" Focusable="True" KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="True" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" Height="300"/>

        <Button Name="btnClose" Focusable="True" IsTabStop="True" Content="Close" Click="btnClose_Click" Width="100"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

This is C# code, it has a bunch of diagnostic traces to show how focus/keyboard events are routed and where the focus is:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Navigation;

namespace WpfWebBrowserTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // watch these events for diagnostics
            EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(UIElement), Keyboard.PreviewKeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler(MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown));
            EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(UIElement), Keyboard.GotKeyboardFocusEvent, new KeyboardFocusChangedEventHandler(MainWindow_GotKeyboardFocus));
            EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(UIElement), FocusManager.GotFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_GotFocus));
        }

        private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // load the browser
            this.webBrowser.NavigateToString("<body contentEditable='true' onload='focus()'>Line 1<br>Line 3<br>Line 3<br></body>");
            this.btnLoad.IsChecked = true;
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // close the form
            if (MessageBox.Show("Close it?", this.Title, MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                this.Close();
        }

        // Diagnostic events

        void MainWindow_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.Print("{0}, source: {1}, {2}", FormatMethodName(), FormatType(e.Source), FormatFocused());
        }

        void MainWindow_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.Print("{0}, source: {1}, {2}", FormatMethodName(), FormatType(e.Source), FormatFocused());
        }

        void MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.Print("{0}, key: {1}, source: {2}, {3}", FormatMethodName(), e.Key.ToString(), FormatType(e.Source), FormatFocused());
        }

        // Debug output formatting helpers

        string FormatFocused()
        {
            // show current focus and keyboard focus
            return String.Format("Focus: {0}, Keyboard focus: {1}, webBrowser.HasFocusWithin: {2}",
                FormatType(FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this)),
                FormatType(Keyboard.FocusedElement),
                ((System.Windows.Interop.IKeyboardInputSink)this.webBrowser).HasFocusWithin());
        }

        string FormatType(object p)
        {
            string result = p != null ? String.Concat('*', p.GetType().Name, '*') : "null";
            if (p == this.webBrowser )
                result += "!!";
            return result;
        }

        static string FormatMethodName()
        {
            return new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;
        }

    }
}
```

**[UPDATE]** The situation doesn't get better if I host [WinForms WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) (in place of, or side-by-side with WPF WebBrowser):

```
<StackPanel Margin="20,20,20,20">
    <ToggleButton Name="btnLoad" Focusable="True" IsTabStop="True" Content="Load" Click="btnLoad_Click" Width="100"/>

    <WebBrowser Name="webBrowser" Focusable="True" KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="True" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" Height="150" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>

    <WindowsFormsHost Name="wfHost" Focusable="True" Height="150" Margin="10,10,10,10">
        <wf:WebBrowser x:Name="wfWebBrowser" />
    </WindowsFormsHost>

    <Button Name="btnClose" Focusable="True" IsTabStop="True" Content="Close" Click="btnClose_Click" Width="100"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The only improvement is that I do see focus events on `WindowsFormsHost`.

**[UPDATE]** An extreme case: two WebBrowser controls with two carets showing at the same time:

```
<StackPanel Margin="20,20,20,20">
    <ToggleButton Name="btnLoad" Focusable="True" IsTabStop="True" Content="Load" Click="btnLoad_Click" Width="100"/>

    <WebBrowser Name="webBrowser" Focusable="True" KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="True" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" Height="150" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
    <WebBrowser Name="webBrowser2" Focusable="True" KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="True" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" Height="150" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>

    <Button Name="btnClose" Focusable="True" IsTabStop="True" Content="Close" Click="btnClose_Click" Width="100"/>
</StackPanel>

this.webBrowser.NavigateToString("<body onload='text.focus()'><textarea id='text' style='width: 100%; height: 100%'>text</textarea></body>");
this.webBrowser2.NavigateToString("<body onload='text.focus()'><textarea id='text' style='width: 100%; height: 100%'>text2</textarea></body>");
```

This also illustrates that the focus handling issue is not specific to `contentEditable=true` content.

Comment: Both WPF and HTML is to blame here. Neither WPF's WebBrowser control is mature enough to handle focus properly, nor the HTML's contentEditable is focus friendly. I fixed similar focus issues with WPF's WebBrowser by adding <form> inside the <body>, putting the content inside <form> and then manually setting focus using `document.forms[0].elements[0].focus();`. Also regarding maintaining caret position with contentEditable, see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194364/maintain-cursor-position-in-contenteditable-div).

Comment: @digitguy, thank you. I'm currently playing with a similar solution: wrapping WebBrowser with UserControl, calling InvokeScript("focus") manually and handling inner HTML window onfocus/onblur events to set WPF focus on UserControl accordingly. Will post here what I'll come up with. It appears the caret problem is not specific to `contentEditable=true`, the same applies to `textarea` or `input type=text`.

Comment: I'd like to link [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437898/why-is-keyboard-focusedelement-null-when-focus-is-inside-windowsformshost-it-br) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417648/inconsistency-in-wpf-command-routing-behavior-depending-on-the-ui-focus-state) questions here as part of my research on the subject.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone else stumbling upon this post and needing to set *keyboard* focus to the browser control (not a particular element within the control, necessarily), this bit of code worked for me.

First, add a project reference (under Extensions in VS) for `Microsoft.mshtml`.

Next, whenever you'd like to focus the browser control (say for example, when the Window loads), simply "focus" the HTML document:

```
// Constructor
public MyWindow()
{
    Loaded += (_, __) =>
    {
        ((HTMLDocument) Browser.Document).focus();
    };
}
```

This will place keyboard focus inside the web browser control, and inside the "invisible" ActiveX window, allowing keys like PgUp / PgDown to work on the HTML page.

If you want to, you might be able to use DOM selection to find a particular element on the page, and try to `focus()` that particular element. I have not tried this myself.

Comment: Nice solution! Works on HTML sites. Now I want to use AdobeReader Plugin to display PDFs. The proble is, that this is not a `HTMLDocument` and I get an exception. It is a "___COM_Object". Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Why does this answer not have more attention?  This was the solution for me after so much searching.

Answer (score 5):

The reason it behaves this way is related to the fact that it's an ActiveX control which itself is a fully windows class (it handles mouse and keyboard interaction).  In fact much of the time you see the component used you'll find it is the main component taking up a full window because of this.  It doesn't have to be done that way but it presents issues.

Here's a forum discussing the exact same issue and it's causes can be clarified by reading the last commentators article links:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1b50fec6-6596-4c0a-9191-32cd059f18f7/focus-issues-with-systemwindowscontrolswebbrowser

To outline the issues you're having

- Tabbing is misbehaving. User needs to hit Tab twice to see the caret (text cursor) inside WebBrowser and be able to type.

  that's because the browser control itself is a window which can be tabbed to.  It doesn't "forward" the tab to it's child elements immediately.

  One way to change this would be to handle the WM message for the component itself but keep in mind that doing so gets tricky when you want the "child" document inside of it to be able to handle messages.

  See: [Prevent WebBrowser control from stealing focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562619/prevent-webbrowser-control-from-stealing-focus) specifically the "answer".  Although their answer doesn't account that you can control whether the component interacts through dialogs with the user by setting the Silent property (may or may not exist in the WPF control... not sure)
- When user switches away from the app (e.g., with Alt-Tab), then goes back, the caret is gone and she is unable to type at all. A physical mouse click into the WebBrowser's window client area is required to get back the caret and keystrokes.
  This is because the control itself has received the focus.  Another consideration is to add code to handle the GotFocus event and to then "change" where the focus goes.  Tricky part is figuring out if this was "from" the document -> browser control or your app -> browser control.  I can think of a few hacky ways to do this (variable reference based on losing focus event checked on gotfocus for example) but nothing that screams elegant.
- Inconsistently, a dotted focus rectangle shows up around WebBrowser (when tabbing, but not when clicking). I could not find a way to get rid of it (FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" does not help).
  I wonder if changing Focusable would help or hinder.  Never tried it but I'm going to venture a guess that if it did work it would stop it from being keyboard navigable at all.
- Internally, WebBrowser never receives the focus. That's true for both logical focus (FocusManager) and input focus (Keyboard). The Keyboard.GotKeyboardFocusEvent and FocusManager.GotFocusEvent events never get fired for WebBrowser (although they both do for buttons in the same focus scope). Even when the caret is inside WebBrowser, FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(mainWindow) points to a previously focused element (a button) and Keyboard.FocusedElement is null. At the same time, ((IKeyboardInputSink)this.webBrowser).HasFocusWithin() returns true.
  People have hit issues with where 2 browser controls both show the focus(well... the caret) or even had a hidden control take the focus.

All in all it's pretty awesome what you can do with the component but it's just the right mix of letting you control/change the behavior along with predefined sets of behavior to be maddening.

**My suggestion would be to try to subclass the messages so you can direct the focus control directly through code and bypass it's window from trying to do so.**

Comment: Shawn, thanks for you thoughts. We did consider taking the "hook" route using [CBT hook](http://goo.gl/6OWPUm), but decided to stay with a more "soft" hack as described in the comments above. One part of the problem is that WPF ActiveX host code doesn't call `IOleInPlaceActiveObject::OnFrameWindowActivate` correctly. Some other focus issues [are not specific](http://goo.gl/lRTQAx) to WB and exist indeed because of using a child window. I hope, at some point Microsoft will port their Modern UI browser as a pure WPF control.