# Does the WPF WebBrowser Control Implement Commands?

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have been trying to use Commands with the WPF `WebBrowser` control (with `DesignMode = "on"`):

#### Xaml (oversimplified):

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
       <Button Command="ToggleBold"/>
       <WebBrowser />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

...but despite the `WebBrowser` accepting keystrokes when I type (and formatting a word as **bold** when I hit `Ctrl+B`) nothing happens when I click the button.  This indicates to me that the `WebBrowser` does not natively implement Commands like a `RichTextBox`.

Can anyone please confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that, WPF `WebBrowser` control doesn't support WPF commands out-of-the-box. You'd need to implement a layer which handles WPF commands and translates them to the corresponding [`IHTMLDocument2::execCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) commands. To do that, you could create a custon control (derived from `UserControl`) and embed the `WebBrowser` control inside it. You cannot derive from `WebBrowser` directly as it's `sealed`.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan - although why this wasn't included in the WPF wrapper class is beyond me.

Comment: @ScottSEA, the WPF wrapper is imperfect in many other ways, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256886/webbrowser-control-keyboard-and-focus-behavior

Answer (score 0):

I am not a WPF expert, but what I know that the Webbrowser control is the same as a real browser in your app, so it render just HTML, and can't understand WPF or asp.net code.

Comment: As I understand it, the `WebBrowser` control wraps the ActiveX IE control... and you'd think that if they were writing a wrapper, they'd add `Command` functionality - basically wrap calls to `execCommand()` with the appropriate .NET `Command`.  Just sayin'.

Comment: what I am sure from that there is nothing called RichTextBox in html

Comment: I was only saying that the `RichTextBox` natively supports Commands, not that it was an HTML control or related to HTML in any way.