# WebBrowser Control - Caret does not appear until click

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm having an issue with the WPF `WebBrowser` control. It seems to have the logical focus (at least, when I press a key, my keyUp/keyDown events are fired), but the caret is not displayed on the control.

In fact, although the keyUp events are fired, nothing is written in the webbrowser since the caret is not displayed.

`Focusable` property is set to `True` not only on the Usercontrol, but also on the WebBrowser control until I click on the box.

I tried setting the focus on the webBrowser:

```
this.webBrowser.Focus();
Keyboard.Focus(this.webBrowser);
```

But also on the mshtml element (webBrowser.Document)

```
this.webBrowser.Document.Focus();
```

The property `Keyboard.FocusedElement` returns `webBrowser`.

This post sounds very similar to my problem, and the solutions posted there are not working in my case. I'm not sure if there's any solution:
[WebBrowser control keyboard and focus behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256886/webbrowser-control-keyboard-and-focus-behavior)

Any hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In addition to that, when moving to another app by using Alt+Tab and then coming back to my app, the caret appears!

Comment: I used `this.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com");` and the caret is visible. It's better to share a code to simply reproduce the problem.